# How can i properly change the key name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to change the key name in my dictionary, the code i'm using is the following:

```
for key in my_dict_other:
    print(key)
    new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key])
    print(new_key)
    my_dict_other[new_key] = my_dict_other.pop(key)
```

The issues i'm having is getting a key error after a few first successful code iterrations

Output:

```
38-7
38-7/[2550, 1651]
13-9
13-9/[2550, 1651]
16-15
16-15/[5100, 3301]
31-0/[5400, 3601]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key])
KeyError: '31-0/[5400, 3601]'
```

and getting the error each time on a different key so can't seem to understand the pattern of the issue or what's wrong with my code

**Edit:** Structure of `my_dict_other` :

```
'41-3': [['2436', '2459', '1901', '2152'],
                      ['2704', '2253', '2442', '2062'],
                      ['2763', '2595', '2498', '2518'],
                      ['2190', '1918', '1970', '1875'],
                      ['3154', '2442', '3023', '2417'],
                      ['3360', '2481', '3252', '2458'],
                      ['653', '1916', '430', '1874'],
```

Structure of `my_dict`:

```
'1-0': [5400, 3601],
 '1-1': [2550, 1651],
 '1-3': [5400, 3601],
 '1-4': [5400, 3601],
 '1-5': [5400, 3601],
```

Comment: showing us the structure of `my_dict` and `my_dict_other` would help a great deal. Just a couple of key-value pairs for each. Are you sure that all the keys contained in `my_dict_other` are in `my_dict` too?

Comment: seems like you don't have that `31-0/[5400, 3601]` key at all. Not to mention a weird keys and values!

Comment: + You are changing the `my_dict_other` as you loop through it. And by **adding** items too. That loop will never end.. And you are adding `key-value` pairs for which the key does not exist in `my_dict`

Comment: Don't modify as you iterate, just create a new dict, like `{key + '/' + str(my_dict[key]): my_dict_other[key] for key in my_dict_other}`

Comment: Edited the question to add the structure of my dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are popping and adding keys from/to a dict while iterating it. Don't do that. You could e.g. loop over a list of keys that you extract:

```
for key in list(my_dict_other):  # loop over key list, not dict itself
    new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key])  # assuming key in my_dict!
    my_dict_other[new_key] = my_dict_other.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code here:

```
for key in my_dict_other:
    new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key])
    my_dict_other[new_key] = my_dict_other.pop(key)
```

1. You are changing the object you are looping through.. That's a *no-no*. Adding elements to it make the loop endless too!
2. You are looping through the keys of `my_dict_other` and doing `my_dict[key]` for each. Are you sure that `my_dict` contains them all? If not, then do `my_dict.get(key, '')` or add an `if` check in there.
3. The biggest fail of them all though and ultimately what causes your code to break is the combination of **1.** & **2.**. You are adding key `'31-0/[5400, 3601]'` in the first iteration and at some point it becomes your `key` (as in `for key in my_dict_other` key) which of course does not exist in the `my_dict` and thus the `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

[For the sake of completeness] In addition to schwobaseggl's answer, you could also write the new key value into a fresh dictionary with new names:

```
fresh = {}
for key in my_dict_other: 
    fresh[(key + '/' + str(my_dict[key]))] = my_dict_other(key)
```

But as Ev.Kounis mentioned, you need to be sure that your my_dict dictionary contains the same keys...The reason you're getting that KeyError from the .pop call is probably due to the fact that the key isn't in your my_dict.